# Fit a sympy functions or convert it to python function

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Let (cos(x)exp(x)) be any simpy function. I want to change the sympy function into the function (a*cos(x) exp(x)+b) and fit the parameters (a,b) to data.

I don't now, if there is a direct way, to fit a sympy function. The pip package symfit 0.2.3 is not working (https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) - there is an error when trying to import parts of the packages.

One can use the sympy function lambdify to create a numpy function like this

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import cos, exp
from sympy import lambdify
x      = symbols('x')
python_formula = lambdify(x,cos(x)*exp(x), 'numpy')
```

I would now multiply my parameters like

```
def function(x,a,b,python_formula):
    return a*python_formula(x) +b
```

Unfortunately, if I use scipy.optimize.curve_fit like

```
optimizedParameters, pcov = opt.curve_fit(function, x_data, y_data);
```

it will take the "python_formula" argument in my function as an optimizable parameter and will crash. I also did not find a way, to specify the fit parameter
(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

If you have an idea, how to generally fit a sympy function or a way to fix the code, I would be thankful to hear it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you install symfit 0.2.3? We are at 0.5.1 by now, and it does exactly what you need :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a function factory, so that the *lambdified* function is bound at the moment of the definition and not when your script is sourced

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import cos, exp
from sympy import lambdify
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
def make_f2opt(lambdified):
    return lambda x, a, b: a*lambdified(x)+b
### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###

x      = symbols('x')
python_formula = lambdify(x,cos(x)*exp(x), 'numpy')

### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
f2opt = make_f2opt(python_formula)
### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###

parameter, covariance = curve_fit(f2opt, x_data, y_data)
```

Comment: Hey, but do you also know, how to put this fitted function back to a sympy function?

Comment: Sympy function? I'd  rather say a Sympy symbolical expression… However `sympy_fun = parameter + cos(x)*exp(x)*covariance`